# Why are GStreamer packages always named "gstreamer1-*"?

Tags: package-management, version, gstreamer

Why are GStreamer packages always named `gstreamer1-*`? What is `1`? Why not just `gtsreamer-*`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GStreamer comes in two primary release flavours: the old, deprecated, unmaintained 0.10 release series and the new, shiny 1.x releases.

Some Linux distributions or software providers may still make the older releases available for compatibility with old software (although I can't find any Linux distribution that still provides GStreamer 0.10 in their current distribution repositories).  For more info about the 0.10 series, [see e.g. Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GStreamer#The_0.10_series).

Release 1.0 was made in the second half of 2012, and this is the current series of releases that people should be using (see a bit further down on that Wikipedia page I just linked to).

It is important to know what major release of an API like GStreamer one is using, as the API usually introduces incompatible changes with the change of major versions.  This is why all GStreamer packages are tagged with `1`; to tell them apart from any old version 0.10 package that may still be in circulation, and to also distinguish them from future versions 2.x and 3.x etc.

See also [the GStremaer FAQ](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/frequently-asked-questions/getting.html?gi-language=c#what-is-the-difference-between-versions-010-and-10) about the differences between versions 0.10 and 1.0.